# Autoinstaller: keep the /home if available, (and automatically add users)

Tags: storage, curtin, autoinstall

What I would like to do is to make an autoinstaller that only installs the OS but would try to keep, and attach, an existing home directory - and automatically make the user(s) again.

But looking through Curtin storage documentation, it seems that there is no way to try to only set up certain storage *if it isn't there*, right? I.e. either you

- wipe everything, format the disk, make partitions, make LVM etc etc and overwrite everything;
- or you keep everything;

But you can't tell Curtin to look if there is anything to keep (then keep it, otherwise make it)?

I tried to

```
    - ptable: gpt
      path: /dev/nvme0n1
      preserve: true
      id: disk-nvm
[...]
    - device: disk-nvm
      size: 536870912
      wipe: superblock
      flag: boot
      number: 1
      preserve: false
    - device: disk-nvm
      type: partition
      id: partition-2
      size: -1
      number: 2
      preserve: true
      grub_device: false
```

... but that would bail out telling me that partition 1 could not be made (yeah, because it was there already). Another setup where I tried to preserve a "home" lvm, wouldn't work out because home just wasn't there, the volume was created but it wasn't formatted (yeah, "If the preserve key is set to true, curtin will not format the partition" - apparently even not if it isn't formatted at all).

Oh, BTW, if anyone got a bright idea how to build an autoinstaller that would detect an existing /home somewhere and automatically add its users, please answer below.

(Auto-adding the users would be a simple trick, add user without password, password expired - I can do *that*, it's the preservation part that puzzles me).